# Ruby: Working in context of some namespace

Tags: ruby, namespaces

Here is a piece of code which uses enum many times:

```
.where("items.state in (#{Workflow::ItemStatus::MOVING},#{Workflow::ItemStatus::WAITING},#{Workflow::ItemStatus::EXECUTING},#{Workflow::ItemStatus::ASSIGNED})")
```

What I do not like is the `Workflow::ItemStatus` namespace repeated many times which produces a long string.

I would like to wrap code in some construction which will allow me to do:

```
.where("items.state in (#{[MOVING, WAITING, EXECUTING, ASSIGNED].join(',')})")
```

Comment: If `Workflow::ItemStatus` is a module, include it.

Comment: @Michael Kohl: Unfortunately, there are two namespaces with synchronized enums: `Proto::ItemStatus` and `Workflow::ItemStatus` (but they are not the same). If I include both modules, names would be ambiguous. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
constants = %i(MOVING WAITING EXECUTING ASSIGNED)
.where("items.state in (?)", constants.map { |c| Workflow::ItemStatus.const_get(c) })
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked for myself a compromise solution out:

```
st = Workflow::ItemStatus
Item.joins(.....).where("items.state in (#{st::MOVING},#{st::WAITING},#{st::EXECUTING},#{st::ASSIGNED})")
```